# Java загадочный компилятор

Tags: java

Не вдаваясь в подробности, есть два экземпляра метода :

```
    public static Map<CustomerServiceType, Double> calculateLossPerService(ServiceNodeAgent<?, ?, ?> scope) {
    Map<CustomerServiceType, Double> resultEnumKeys = Maps.newHashMap();
    Map<CustomerServiceType, Long> serviceTypesToDroppedPackets = scope.getDroppedPacketsByServiceType().reduceRows();
    Map<CustomerServiceType, Long> serviceTypesToReceivedPackets = scope.getReceivedPacketsByServiceType().reduceRows();
    for (Map.Entry<CustomerServiceType, Long> customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry : serviceTypesToReceivedPackets.entrySet()) {
        Long droppedPackets = serviceTypesToDroppedPackets.get(customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry.getKey());
        Long receivedPackets = Math.max(customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry.getValue(), 1);
        double result = droppedPackets / (double) receivedPackets;
        resultEnumKeys.put(customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry.getKey(), CommonUtils.clip(0.0, result, 1.0));
    }
    return resultEnumKeys;
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------

```
    public static Map<CustomerServiceType, Double> calculateLossPerService(ServiceNodeAgent scope) {
    Map<CustomerServiceType, Double> resultEnumKeys = Maps.newHashMap();
    Map serviceTypesToDroppedPackets = scope.getDroppedPacketsByServiceType().reduceRows();
    Map serviceTypesToReceivedPackets = scope.getReceivedPacketsByServiceType().reduceRows();
    for (Object customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry : serviceTypesToReceivedPackets.entrySet()) {
        Map.Entry<CustomerServiceType, Long> customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry1 =
                (Map.Entry<CustomerServiceType, Long>) customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry;//<---тут
         Long droppedPackets = (Long) serviceTypesToDroppedPackets.get(customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry1.getKey());
         Long receivedPackets =         Math.max(customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry1.getValue(), 1);
         double result = droppedPackets / (double) receivedPackets;
         resultEnumKeys.put(customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry1.getKey(),    CommonUtils.clip(0.0, result, 1.0));
     }
     return resultEnumKeys;
 }
```

Во втором компилятор ругался, что *Unchecked cast* в строке *//<---тут*
После исправлений, приобрел вид 1 фрагмента.
Вопрос, почему теперь компилятор перестал ругаться?

Answer (score 1):

Во втором фрагменте переменная `customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry` имеет тип `Object`. Очевидно, что за `Object` может на самом деле скрываться любой друг тип. Следовательно любой кастинг будет небезопасен.

В первом фрагменте переменная `customerServiceTypeDoubleEntry` имеет четко определенный тип, соответствующий типу элементов в `serviceTypesToReceivedPackets`. Компилятор видит это и не имеет претензий.

Comment: это я не совсем корректно задал вопрос. Меня интересует, почему изменение типа аргумента функции на _ServiceNodeAgent<?, ?, ?>_ помогло компилятору сориентироваться?

Comment: @voipp Ваши фрагменты отличаются не только типом аргумента функции, но и практически всеми указанными типами. У меня нет достаточной информации для ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Если во втором куске кода изменить аргумент заданным образом, то исчезнут все варнинги. Первый кусок кода - это уже с рефакторингом. В итоге, вопрос сводится, почему замена аргумента так помогла ?